# Consumir WebService (ApiRest) a través de JAVA

Tags: java, webservice, rest, netbeans-8.2

Soy nuevo aca en la comunidad, y queria contarles mi inquietud para recibir un poco de ayuda. Lo que me sucede es que necesito consumir un web service de una empresa, un apirest, y si es posible consumirlo desde JAVA estoy utilizando a traves de Netbeans 8.2, osea realizar una aplicación para obtener los datos de este ws. Cada consulta que se hace, es necesario enviar un token mas el dato que necesitemos consultar.
ejemplo:

https:\paginawebservice/ciudades/1
(el 1 seria el id de algun pais, el cual permite a la consulta que nos liste o obtengamos todas las ciudades de un pais).

Lo que quiera es que me den una mano, de como puedo armar un estructura en el cual pueda pasar ese token, el dato para la consulta y poder consumirlo para obtener estos datos del cual arriba comente, como se define esa URL y poder armar metodos para ralizar las peticiones.

Utilizando herramientas como el Postman, me funciona ya que me permite configurar un header que ahi definiria el token, y luego con el metodo GET, definiendo la URL obtengo los datos.

Espero que se haya entendido, no les brindo codigo porque ese seria mi punto, pero como para tener una idea les agradeceria que me puedan brindar sus conocimientos. Muchas gracias.

Comment: espero te sirva aca hay varios ejemplos https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request